# Can you use regular expression in CSS img[alt=*]?

Tags: css

For the following image html:

```
<img src="/some.png" alt="something" />
```

In CSS, you can target an `img` element with a specific `alt` value:

```
img[alt="something"] {
  width: 5em;
}
```

How can I select all `img` elements with text in the `alt` attribute?  I was thinking of something like:

```
img[alt="*"]
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can target elements which have an `alt` attribute like this

```
img[alt]
```

I believe this will also match those with an empty `alt` attribute however. I don't think you can specifically target those with a nonempty value. You could write a rule to match those with empty values and undo ignore the rules which would otherwise be applied (via `!important`) although that gets messy.

Comment: Yes, that will do the job. You do not need to filter out attributes as by specifications no empty attributes are valid

Comment: Agreed @Dmitri. Although I do often see people leaving empty alt attributes to avoid warnings, so I thought I would mention. However, I think your point of it being against standards is more important.